# Remover cor de seleção da linha do JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Pode parecer besteira, mas não consigo achar o método para remover a cor da seleção de quando o mouse clica na linha. Tenho uma tabela com linhas vermelhas e azuis, cores azuis são linhas que significam uma ação e vermelhas outras ações. No entanto quando seleciono a linha, a cor é sobreposta pelo o azul opaco de seleção padrão do JTable, claro que ao clicar em outra linha a cor definida da linha clicada volta ao normal. Enfim, minha dúvida é, como remover esse azul opaco padrão do JTable que sinaliza a seleção da linha?

Abaixo está meu código, todas condições funcionam, exceto "isSelect", onde deveria deixa a linha com a cor que já existe, e não sobrepor com a cor de seleção.

> Código

```
package commons;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

import model.SdkDynRellation;
import view.ViewInit;

import com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.field.IsSetFieldRenderer;


public class ColorCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {


private List<String> list;

public ColorCellRenderer() {
    super();
}

public ColorCellRenderer(List<String> list2) {
    list = list2;
    setOpaque(true);
}

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    final JLabel cellComponent = (JLabel) super
            .getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected,
                    hasFocus, row, column);


    Object val = table.getValueAt(row, 0);
    Object check = table.getValueAt(row, 1);


    if (!AuxClass.isBegin) {
        if (list.contains(val.toString())
                && check.toString().equals("true")) {
            cellComponent.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            cellComponent.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        } else {
            if (check.toString().equals("true") && new SdkDynRellation().getIndexes().contains(val))
            {
                cellComponent.setBackground(Color.RED);
                cellComponent.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            } 
            else
            {
                if (check.toString().equals("true"))
                {
                    cellComponent.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                    cellComponent.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                }
                else 
                {
                    cellComponent.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                    cellComponent.setForeground(Color.black);
                }

            }


        }


        if (isSelected)
        {
            cellComponent.setBackground(getBackground());
        }
    } else {
        if (list.contains(val.toString())
                && check.toString().equals("true")) {
            cellComponent.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            cellComponent.setBackground(Color.RED);
        } else {

            cellComponent.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            cellComponent.setForeground(Color.black);
        }

    }




    return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected,
            hasFocus, row, column);
}
```

}

Comment: No *renderer* execute `setOpaque(true)`. Olhe também o método [setSelectionBackground](http://www.javadocexamples.com/javax/swing/JList/setSelectionBackground%28Color%20selectionBackground%29.html).

Comment: @QMechanic73 ainda não resolveu meu problema, editei a pergunta e coloquei meu código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar um *renderer* customizado para a tabela. Exemplo:

```
class CustomRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            if (isSelected) { // Se a célula está selecionada
                c.setForeground(Color.black); // ou outra cor
            } else {
                c.setForeground(Color.gray); // ou outra cor
            }
            return c;
        }
    }
```

Depois só passar o *renderer* para a tabela:

```
CustomRenderer tableRenderer = new CustomRenderer ();
   for (int i = 0; i < tableModel.getColumnCount(); i++) { // Adicionar o renderer para cada coluna
      jTable.setDefaultRenderer(jTable.getColumnClass(i), tableRenderer);
   }
```

Sugiro dar uma lida em http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Comment: A linha que for selecionada já está com o background alterado, na verdade o que eu desejo é não demonstrar quando uma linha está selecionada. Pois cada linha, possui um checkbox na coluna ao lado. Ou seja, se fossemos pensar na possibilidade de utilizar o "isSelect" ele deveria ser transparente.

Comment: Esqueci de comentar, ja estou utilizando um renderer para definir as cores de background das linhas.

Comment: O código anterior não funcionava porque o método da superclasse sobrescrevia as modificações. Já corrigi. Para não perceber que tem linha selecionada, basta colocar a cor do background igual ao normal, no seu caso, azul ou vermelho.